# Move ROW upon selecting a specific option from drop down menu

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am looking to use Google Sheets to keep track of my jobs. I have a spreadsheet set up so the status of a job is indicated by a dropdown menu. When a job is completed I would select "Closed" from the drop-down. I would love for it to atomically move the entire row to another sheet upon selecting closed. This sheet would be strictly for closed jobs and keep the current sheet only for live jobs.

Answer (score 0):

## "...in the meantime..." solution:

paste the **`QUERY`** formula on Sheet2 and everytime you close the job, just right-click the row, select option to **resize row** and set it on 2px, or better - select **hide row**

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A2:D; "select * where C='Closed'"; 0)
```

### _______________________________________________________________

> [image: 1]
>
> [image: 2]
>
> [image: 3]
>
> [image: 5]